# PHP number format

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have this string :

```
000000000000100
```

and need to convert it to:

```
1,00
```

So, the rules are:

1. Divide the number by 100 and use a comma as decimal separator
2. Strip leading zeros
3. Keep two decimals

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you just need one number before the decimal separator? Do you need more than 2 decimals if present? E.g. should `000000000001200` become `1,200`, `1,20` or `12,00`?

Comment: I need only 2 number after comma!000000000001200 -> 12,00

Comment: We need to know what the rules should be for the conversion. One single example is not sufficient. Looks like this is: (a) division by 100; (b) removal of leading zeroes; (c) use of comma (`,`) for decimal point. Am I right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual page on `number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )

If you want numbers like `123456` be formatted as `1234,45`, use:

```
echo number_format($number / 100, 2, ",", "");
```

If you need a dot as thousands separator (`1.234,56`):

```
echo number_format($number / 100, 2, ",", ".");
```

The zeros are automatically removed by PHP when converting the string to a number.

Comment: This confused me for ages because I was thinking "but where does `", "` (comma space) appear in the end result".  Now I see the comma separates the values and one is within quotes.  :D

Answer (score 8):

```
string number_format ( float $number , 
                       int $decimals = 0 ,
                       string $dec_point = '.' ,
                       string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
// divide by 100 to shift ones place.
echo number_format((int)'000000000000100' / 100,2,',','');
```

Comment: err, **divide** is what i meant.

Comment: Brad, you should write the outcome as well so it's a clearer example for noobs like me.  I assume it is 0000000000001,00.