# PHP number format 2 decimal places

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308687/php-number-format)

The following code out puts a figure for shipping cost based on a currency conversion that happens elsehwere, but it outputs with many decimal places. Can I alter something here that will produce a number with just 2 decimal places?

```
if(isset($_POST['ShippingMethod'])){
            $order['data']  .= "\r\n ========== Shipping Cost ========== \r\n\r";
            $order['data'] .="\r\n Shipping Method Cost: ". $_SESSION['currency_symbol'].$_POST['ShippingMethod']. " \r\n";
            $form['price']['shipping'] +=$_POST['ShippingMethod'];
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

have a look at http://php.net/number_format and if its related to currency, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php