# How to print integer with 0 as a decimal value?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a number coming from database like this 7.0 or 7.7 . When I print the value the 7.7 prints as it is but 7.0 is printed as only 7. Is there are way to print 7.0 as 7.0 . I am using twig template in sf2.

This is how I am printing those values

```
{{ object.value }}
```

Comment: Use `floatval()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the right way to do it but at least I have got something working

First I checked the length, if the length were 1 or 2 I printed the value and appended `.0` else I simply just printed the value.

```
{% if (device.ph_value|length == 1 or device.ph_value|length == 2)%}
    {{device.ph_value}}.0
{% else %}
    {{device.ph_value}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How do you check the length for `7` or `77`?

Comment: by converting it into string

Comment: Oops, my example was wrong, what if you have `777`?

Comment: Hi @A.L , the value can only be either a one digit or two digit after the decimal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `number_format` Twig filter, as example:

```
{{ object.value|number_format }}
```

Full example:

```
{{ 9800.333|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

More info in the [doc here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html)

Comment: Should it be `number_format(1, '.', ',')` instead? It looks like the OP want only one decimal.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo number_format(object.value,1);
```

This should type out 7.0 as 7.0 instead of 7

Comment: but what if the number is like 7.89 . I want to show it as is. Thanks for the answer man

Comment: My advice is to use strlen to read the lenght of the string and as in this case subtract 1. Strlen() =3 -1 =2. Number_format(vvv,2); but you need to code it

Comment: Actually i am using the twig template so the normal php function is not going to work

Comment: you can write an twig filter to wrap normal php function.

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html this filter is avaliable for twig

Comment: @A.L it's not. The question was taged with php, thus answer in php. No need to downvote.

Comment: @Andreas Yes the question is tagged as PHP but the OP use Twig: *I am using twig template in sf2*. I'm sorry but for me this answer is off-topic. If this question was about PHP, it would be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308687/php-number-format

Answer (score -2):

You could do something further to preserve the value.

```
   $integer = filter_var(7.7, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

    print_r($integer);

    output
    7.7
```

Comment: How do you use this in a Twig template?